# Rendering database query with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have setup a MongoDB database, a very basic front end with a search bar that posts a query, and using node.js and express to send the query to the database. I have successfully queried the db and returned the search items, but its only in the console right now (through a console.log(results)). Where I am stuck, is I don't know how to get the returned search results into the front end dynamically. I was researching things like ng-repeat with Angular, but I'm stuck. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: When angular loads, have it make an HTTP request to node, which runs whatever and `res.send(response)`. Then you can use angular to populate whatevers with a `$scope` variable

Comment: Ok, so I assume that you have already properly implemented the `.then(successCallback)` promise in which you do the `console.log(results)`.

You should have a controller somewhere, for the view you want to update, and the successCallback function should actually be able to push the results to the scope of this controller. Then a simple `ng-repeat` for example, will allow you to see the results in your page.

Can you show us your code, so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working plunker example (not from me) hope it helps.

http://embed.plnkr.co/lrn0NNMNbIVE4rS4Fytd/preview

The functionality shown sounds like it could help you

The REST Call should be made within a service (`userRepoService`) which you inject into your controller (`userController`). There you can set the data on the scope and use it inside your html (`index.html`).